# Filter array based on multiple filters

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, filter

I have a table that I want to be able to apply multiple filters to. My current code will filter by email OR status but I want it to do both so a user can refine the results.

I've tried adding `&&` instead of `||` in the `filteredInvoices` variable.

I allow the user to select the filters they want to use and store this in an object in useState. I also keep track of the status if the filter is active or inactive.

```
const [filter, setFilter] = useState({active: false})
```

A filter object where a user has selected their filters would look like this:

```
filter: {active: true, customerEmail: 'johndoe@gmail.com', status: 'open'}
```

When a user applies this filter to the table I call a function called `updateFilter()` in useEffect when the filter is changed. This will then set the filtered array to state when is then iterated over in the `return`.

```
const updateFilter = () => {
    const filteredInvoices = invoices.filter((inv) => {
        const emailMatch = filter.customerEmail && inv.customerEmail.toLowerCase().includes(filter.customerEmail.toLowerCase())
        const statusMatch = inv.status === filter.status
        return emailMatch || statusMatch
    })
    setListToRender(filteredInvoices)
}

useEffect(() => {
    if (filter.active) {
        updateFilter()
    }

}, [filter])
```

The status that is being filtered is an array of objects.

How am I able to filter by multiple condiitions that are added into the filter object?

Is there a common design for this that would allow me to add additional filters to the filter object and it also work?

For example - johndoe@gmail.com has 10 invoices - 3 open, 4 paid and 3 void. If the filter object looks like this:

How can I filter to show only invoices for that customer that are open.

Thanks in advance for any advice!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you want to be able to not just match specific key-value pairs, but may also need to do stuff like pre-processing of the value before filtering (like you do with converting email to lower case), then a generic approach might work best for you. You can have something like this

```
const updateFilter = () => {
    const filteredInvoices = invoices.filter(invoice => {
    let validInvoice = true;
    
    for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(filter)) {
      if (Array.isArray(value)) {
        if (!value.includes(invoice[key])) {
          validInvoice = false;
        }
      }
      else if (typeof value === 'function') {
        if (!value(invoice[key])) {
          validInvoice = false;
        }
      }
      else {
        if (value !== invoice[key]) validInvoice = false;
      }
    }
    
    return validInvoice;
  });
  
  setListToRender(filteredInvoices)
}
```

With this approach, you can have a filter that has either raw values, functions or arrays. Like so:

```
const filter = {
    // This will check if the invoice 'active' property is true
    active: true,
    // This will check that the status is NOT equal to pending
    status: (status) => status !== 'pending',
    // This will check if the email matches ANY of these values
    email: ['john@doe.com', 'cho@mumma.com']
};
```

This approach allows more nuance than the simple key/value matching approach, and can let you customise your filters more deeply

Answer (score 1):

You can use `filter` and `every` array methods to do the filter.

```js
const invoices = [
 {active: false , customerEmail: 'joedoe@gmail.com', status: 'paid'},
 {active: false , customerEmail: 'sam@gmail.com', status: 'paid'},
 {active: true , customerEmail: 'michael@gmail.com', status: 'void'},
 {active: true , customerEmail: 'adam@gmail.com', status: 'paid'}, 
 {active: true , customerEmail: 'johndoe@gmail.com', status: 'open'}
]

const filter = {active: true, customerEmail: 'johndoe@gmail.com', status: 'open'}

const selectedFilterKeys = Object.keys(filter)

const filteredInvoices = invoices.filter(invoice => selectedFilterKeys.every(key => 
      filter[key] === invoice[key]
))

console.log("filteredInvoices", filteredInvoices)
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Overview

Filtering is usually more performant as an API request to a backend service but is entirely doable on the front end. I'd also think that you'd want this to occur on an event rather than within `useEffect`. That being said, here are a couple of options for filtering.

#### Option 1

Add conditions for each filterable property on the invoice object.

```
const filteredInvoices = invoices.filter((inv) => {
  const isEmailMatch = inv.customerEmail.toLowerCase() === filter.customerEmail.toLowerCase();
  const isStatusMatch = inv.status === filter.status;

  // Add other matches here.

  return isEmailMatch && isStatusMatch;
 });
```

#### Option 2

This would require extracting `status` out of the `filter` state. In my opinion, this solution is more scalable.

```
const [active, setActive] = useState(false); // Extracting active.
const [filter, setFilter] = useState({});

const updateFilter = () => {
  const filteredInvoices = invoices.filter((item) => {
    for (const key in filter) {
      if (item[key] === undefined || item[key] !== filter[key])
        return false;
    }
    return true;
  });
};

useEffect(() => {
  if (active) updateFilter();
}, [filter]);
```